# I am trying to get ActiveCell value in excel through VB.Net.

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to get ActiveCell value in excel through VB.Net. But i am getting error "ActiveCell is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level".

Answer (score 0):

Check if the excel sheet from which you are pulling data is locked.

Comment: I am opening the excel through vb. before even running the script, i am getting error.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the selected cell value from excel through VB.Net?

Comment: Can you mention each step you are carrying out? This will help track down the issue.

Comment: excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        excelapp.Visible = True
        excel = excelapp.WorkBooks.Open(filename)
        sheet1 = excel.Sheets(sheetName)

        MsgBox("select component and click on ok")
        sheet1.Activate()
        ActiveCell.Value = "ABC"
        MsgBox(ActiveCell.Address)

Comment: sorry.. i m new to stack overflow. having trouble pasting the code as it is

Comment: excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    excelapp.Visible = True

Comment: At what point in the above code the above code error is generated? If it is at ActiveCell.Value = "ABC" it means all the cells in shee1 are locked. If the script generates error while opening the workbook it means previous run has caused a lock on the work book and you would need to terminate the excel processes locking the work book. I don't remember if COM components can be explicity cleared in VB but if possible do so so that processes are terminated and files are not locked.

Comment: sheet1.Activate()
     ActiveCell.Value = "ABC"

Comment: it is not even allowing me to execute.. ActiveCell is underlined and the error msg is that it is not declared

Comment: try using sheet1.ActiveCell.Value = "ABC"

Comment: if i delete that line and execute, the excel is opening

Comment: tried that also.. Not working.. code stops at that line

Comment: Is the error message same when you use sheet1.ActiveCell.Value = "ABC" or something else? Please post the error message.

Comment: when i use sheet1.ActiveCell.Value = "ABC", there is no error msg but, execution stops at that line

Comment: try replacing ActiveCell.Value = "ABC" with sheet1.Application.ActiveCell.Value = "ABC" it should work I believe. If it works it would show the value in the excel sheet changed.

Comment: Yeah.. Its working.. Thank you very much for your help :)